# RF Input Sensitivity

Tags: rf

I read in a datasheet that the Input sensitivity of the AD4002 (RFin) is -10dBm to 0dBm.

I know how to convert this to a voltage drop over a resistor, say 50ohm.

But I got myself confused over the exact definition of input sensitivity.

Is it the power that should flow into the pin of the chip?

Or is it the power delivered to a 50ohm termination resistor on the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dBm is power relative to 1 mW , so 0 dBM is 1 mW of input power to the device. You need to know the input impedance of the device to calculate the voltage level of the input signal. If it is 50 ohms, you don't put a 50 ohm resistor across the input.

Comment: Thanks! I think you answered my question. The input impedance is 500 ohms, so input voltage is 0.2V(RMS) to 0.7V(RMS). Now, if I terminate the input with a resistor to match my generator output, should I calculate the input power as the power delivered to the 500 ohms resistor? (500 ohms || x ohms)

Comment: Your signal generator presumably has a 50R impedance, so you need a 450R series resistor to match the 500R input impedance of the device. Just use a 500R load resistance representing the DUT, and adjust the generator to give you your required input signal, then remove the 500R resistor and feed the signal directly into the DUT, still using the 450R series resistance.

Comment: Oh, just a follow up question: If the generator has 50R output impedance, the termination impedance at the end of the generator cable should be 50R, to avoid reflection in the cable? (Assuming my cable is longer than quarter wave length) Or am I missing something?